# Realm: bcsymbolmap is missing from working copy

Tags: ios, xcode, realm

I'm trying to include Realm 2.0.3 and RealmSwift 2.0.3 iOS Swift 2.3 as dynamic framework binaries in my project. I find that they take too long to compile.

I'm able to build my project and run it in the simulator just fine, but when I archive I'm receiving this error:

[image]

This is how I'm including the frameworks (simply drag and drop into project):

[image]
Help!

Comment: Hmm, how are you integrating the frameworks into your project exactly? Realm Swift isn't available as a static framework, so something doesn't seem right here.

Comment: Hi @TiM, please see screenshot above. It may NOT be a static framework - not sure if it's static, dynamic, binary

Comment: Ahh okay! Yep, those are the icons for dynamic frameworks then. Did you remember to add them to the 'Embedded Binaries' section of your app project as well?

Answer (score 1):

Per @TiM's suggestion, in the target's Build Phases I made sure that the two dynamic frameworks are added in in these sections:

- Link Binary with Library
- Embed Frameworks

Dragging and dropping the frameworks in the project does NOT automatically add them to Embed Framworks

Comment: Awesome! Glad I was able to help! Yeah, it appears to be a shortcoming of dynamic frameworks, but dragging them into the Xcode project does not include the setting that ensures the frameworks will be embedded in the final bundle. Also, make sure you follow the final step on Realm's installation tutorial regarding the strip-frameworks build script, or else your app submission will still fail: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#installation